# Java : assign a type as parameter and use generic in constructor

Tags: java, generics

I need to assign a type to an object (as private variable) because this must represent the type on which i cast all values returned by this object's method.

But at same time i need to use generics in some methods (some of these methods are constructor overload) so i can constrain the input parameters.

Eg :

```
class MyClass <T>
{
      public <A> MyClass ( A param ) { //something }

      public T call () { return (T) //some expression }
}
```

Is this right ? 
Or the use of A on the constructor could conflict with T on the class (in some cases)?
Is the use of T on the class a misunderstanding of mine?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is fine. That creates a generic constructor, and type parameter `A` has nothing to do with the type parameter `T`.

Comment: Great! 
Exactly what i hoped ^^

Comment: I'm guessing XY problem here.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: your constructor might as well be declared as `public MyClass(Object param)`

Comment: @Judge Mental, you are not so far, my error is started from my unawareness about java type's erasure, my previous example would be an attempt to store some type information for runtime execution.
The idea was that i would heavily cast, all my call's return type (when i use some generic's functions) in automatic way.
But seems that this approach can not work in java.